# Why am I getting an error while calling Http Request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

**I want to reach the list of participants of a spesific Teams meeting by using Postman. But I'm getting an error.**

my Http Request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/7531d31f-d10d-44de-802f-c569dbca451c/participants

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-10-26T16:50:16",
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the detailed request id, timestamp - its needed for analysis...

Comment: Glad the you fixed the problem. You may want to share how you fixed it, show it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about the tokens .I got the response by using app access token instead of user token, finally it worked.